# Can we have multiple configuration for same database in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project, where a common module is made abstract (COMMON) and it uses JPA repositories.

Then I made uber jar COMMON module started using in another spring boot project (CLIENT) which also uses its own JPA repositories.

The configuration I need for COMMON and CLIENT are same.

However the problem is..

If I mention the repository and entity packages of COMMON in the configuration of CLIENT, the bean of CLIENT repository is not getting constructed.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"COMMON_REPO, CLIENT_REPO" }) //failing to construct CLIENT repo bean
```

If I define a new configuration for COMMON with same Data-source credential as client, then the bean of COMMON repositories is not getting created.

```
//Configuration-1
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"COMMON_REPO" })...

//Configuraton-2 same as Configuration-1
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"CLIENT_REPO" })... 

// COMMON repo bean is not getting constructed.

Error: Error creating bean with name 'workflowRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#60410fb3' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#60410fb3': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Sprint boot version: 2.0.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple configurations for the same database in spring boot.

Use 2 different classes for Configuration-1 and Configuration-2 with @Profile annotation, specify environment or profile in @Profile.

Based on the environment you deployed your application, the configuration file will be active.

Comment: Both will be deployed in same environment, as this a jar used by client